# ANNNOUNNNCCCEEERRR VOICCCEEE

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a function that takes a string of letters and spaces (no need to handle non-letters) and performs the ANNOUNCER VOICE translation algorithm as follows:

- First, uppercase everything.
- For each word,

  - *Elongate* each consonant cluster by tripling each letter; except, if the word *begins* with a consonant cluster, do not elongate that cluster. For example, `other` should become `OTTTHHHEEERRR` but `mother` should become `MOTTTHHHEEERRR`.
  - *Elongate* the final vowel by tripling it.
- In both cases of *elongation*, if you're tripling a letter, first coalesce it with duplicate letters on either side. For example, `hill` should become `HIIILLL` and `bookkeeper` should become `BOOKKKEEPPPEEERRR`.
- For the purposes of this challenge, `y` counts as a consonant.
- Clarification/simplification: You may assume that each pair of words is separated by a single space, and that the input contains no consecutive spaces, and that the input will not be the empty string.
- Shortest code wins!

Test vectors:

```
> sunday sunday
SUNNNDDDAAAYYY SUNNNDDDAAAYYY
> mia hamm
MIAAA HAAAMMM
> chester alan arthur
CHESSSTTTEEERRR ALLLAAANNN ARRRTTTHHHUUURRR
> attention please
ATTTENNNTTTIOOONNN PLEASSSEEE
> supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
SUPPPERRRCCCALLLIFFFRRRAGGGILLLISSSTTTICCCEXXXPPPIALLLIDDDOCCCIOUUUSSS
> moo
MOOO
> Aachen
AACCCHHHEEENNN
> Oooh
OOOHHH
> grifffest
GRIFFFEEESSSTTT
> k
K
> aaaabbbbc
AAAABBBBCCC
```

---

Here's a reference implementation which I would move to an answer except that as of this morning the question's been closed. :P

```
import itertools,re
def j(s):return re.match('^[AEIOU]+$',s)
def c(s):return ''.join(sum(([h,h,h]for h in[k for k,g in itertools.groupby(s)]),[]))
def v(s):
 while len(s)>=2 and s[-2]==s[-1]:s=s[:-1]
 return s+s[-1]+s[-1]
def a(n):
 r=''
 for w in n.split():
  if r:r+=' '
  ss=re.split('([AEIOU]+)', w.upper())
  for i,s in enumerate(ss):
   r += [v(s),s][any(j(t) for t in ss[i+1:])]if j(s)else[s,c(s)][i>0]
 return r
while 1:print a(raw_input('> '))
```

Comment: A request for the future: please avoid words and phrases like *consonant cluster*, *coalesce*, and *elongation*. A non-native English speaker like myself might need a dictionary to understand your post.

Comment: It should be the vowels that are "elongated" :(

Comment: What is consonant cluster?

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 175 bytes

```apl
1↓' +'⎕R' '⊢'[AEIOU][^AEIOU]+ '⎕R{m/⍨1,3×2≠/m←⍵.Match}'([AEIOU])\1*([^AEIOU]*? )' ' [AEIOU]' ' [^ AEIOU]+' '([^AEIOU ])\1*'⎕R'\1\1\1\2' '&' '&' '\1\1\1'⊢'$| |^'⎕R'  '⊢1(819⌶)⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9OCO/tOS/4aO2yeoK2uqP@qYGqSuoP@papB4d5@jq6R8aq60AFq021n/UsepR71Y938SS5IxadY1oiLxmjKGWBkyxlr2CJlC/AlQOzIxTgBoE5MEUKoC1QayLMQRDI6C0GhRDhMDOUKlRqImDugvsMEMNC0PLRz3bNB/1zgN54L8CGID9wVVcmpeSWKkAobiQZXIzExUyEnNzUQSTM1KLS1KLFBJzEvMUEotKMkqLUOQTS0pS80oy8/MUCnJSE4tTuVDtKkgtSk7MyUwrSkzPzMksLslMTq0oyASKpOQnZ@aXFqM6ID8fAA)

`⍞` prompt for character input

`1(819⌶)` convert to uppercase (819 ≈ Big)

`⊢` pass the result further (serves to separate the strings and the 1)

`'$| |^'⎕R'  '` **R**eplace:
 the end, any space, and the beginning
 → two spaces

`⊢` pass the result further (serves to separate two groups of strings)

`'([AEIOU])\1*([^AEIOU]*? )' ' [AEIOU]' ' [^ AEIOU]+' '([^AEIOU ])\1*'⎕R'\1\1\1\2' '&' '&' '\1\1\1'` **R**eplace:
 any number of identical vowels and any number of non-vowels and a space
 → the vowel thrice and the unmodified consonants
 a space and a vowel
 → themselves
 a space and a consonant cluster
 → themselves
 a run of identical consonants
 → three of those vowels

`'[AEIOU][^AEIOU]+ '⎕R{`…`}` **R**eplace:
 a run of non-vowels and a space
 → the result of the following anonymous function with the namespace `⍵` as argument:
  `⍵.Match` the text that was found
  `m←` assign that to `m`
  `2≠/` pair-wise different-from
  `3×` multiply by three
  `1,` prepend one
  `m/⍨` use that to replicate `m`

`⊢` pass the result further (serves to separate two strings)

`' +'⎕R' '` **R**eplace:
 one or more spaces
 → with a single space

`1↓` drop the initial letter (a space)

Comment: Does this work? `1↓' +'⎕R' '⊢'[AEIOU][^AEIOU]+ '⎕R{m/⍨1,3×2≠/m←⍵.Match}'([AEIOU])\1*([^AEIOU]*? )' ' [AEIOU]' ' [^ AEIOU]+' '([^AEIOU ])\1*'⎕R(s,'\2')'&' '&'(s←6⍴'\1')⊢'$| |^'⎕R'  '⊢1(819⌶)⍞`

Comment: ^ Saves two bytes if it works ^

Answer (score 5):

## APL, 90 bytes

```
{1↓∊{s←{⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵}⋄x↑⍨¨(3⌈≢¨s⍵)⌊≢¨x←s⍵/⍨(1+2×{⌽<\⌽⍵}∨~∧∨\)⍵∊'AEIOU'}¨w⊂⍨w=⊃w←' ',1(819⌶)⍵}
```

Explanation:

- `1(819⌶)⍵`: convert to uppercase
- `w⊂⍨w=⊃w←' ',`: split on spaces
- `{`...`}¨`: for each word...

  - `s←{⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵}`: `s` is  a function that splits a string into groups of contiguous matching characters
  - `⍵∊'AEIOU'`: mark the vowels
  - `(`...`)`: see which characters to triplicate

    - `~∧∨\`: all consonants past the first vowel,
    - `{⌽<\⌽⍵}`: the last vowel.
    - `2×`: multiply the bit vector by two,
    - `1+`: and add one. Now all selected characters have `3` and the rest have `1`.
  - `⍵/⍨`: replicate each character in `⍵` by the given amount
  - `x←s`: split it up into strings of matching characters, and store this in `x`.
  - `(3⌈≢¨s⍵)`: the length of each group of matching characters in the input word, with a maximum of 3.
  - `⌊≢¨`: the minimum of that and the lengths of the groups in `x`.
  - `x↑⍨¨`: make each group be that length
- `1↓∊`: flatten the result and drop the first character (the space that was added at the beginning to help with splitting)

Comment: You beat Adám ... wow.

Comment: very neat! If you shuffle it around a bit and write it as a program (using prompt as suggested by Adám) you can shave off another 15 bytes: `1↓∊{c/⍨(≢¨g)⌈3×((⌽<\∘⌽)∨~∧∨\)'AEIOU'∊⍨c←⊃¨g←⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵}¨w⊂⍨w=⊃w←' ',1(819⌶)⍞`

Answer (score 4):

## JS (ES6), <s>138</s> <s>134</s> 129 bytes

```
s=>s.toUpperCase()[r="replace"](/(\w)\1/g,"$1")[r](/[AEIOU](?=[^AEIOU]*( |$))/g,s=>s+s+s)[r](/\B./g,s=>/[AEIOU]/.test(s)?s:s+s+s)
```

WAAAYYY TOOO MAAANNNYYY BYYYTTTEEESSS. Contains `AEIOU` 3 times, but I can't golf those into one.

[-4 bytes thanks to HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133642/72412)

#### Ungolfed

```
function v(str){
    return str.toUpperCase().replace(/(\w)\1/g,"$1").replace(/[AEIOU](?=[^AEIOU]*( |$))/g,s=>s+s+s).replace(/\B./g,s=>[..."AEIOU"].includes(s)?s:s+s+s);
}
```

*I like to write, not read code.*

Comment: "WAAAYYY TOOO MAAANNNYYY BYYYTTTEEESSSS" ... is in first place, ahead of APL.

Comment: I don't know JS, but can you replace `s=>/[AEIOU]/.test(s)` with `/[AEIOU]/.test`?

Comment: @musicman523 sadly, no, because it is the conditional in a ternary 
 operator statement.

Comment: FYI, your handling of consonant clusters appears to be slightly incorrect; the proper output would be `WAAAYYY TOOO MAAANNNYYY BYTEEESSS` (i.e. don't elongate the initial cluster `BYT`).

Comment: Well, was in first place.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 417 bytes

Here's a reference implementation in Python. Not terribly golfed.

```
import itertools,re
def j(s):return re.match('^[AEIOU]+$',s)
def c(s):return ''.join(sum(([h,h,h]for h in[k for k,g in itertools.groupby(s)]),[]))
def v(s):
 while len(s)>=2 and s[-2]==s[-1]:s=s[:-1]
 return s+s[-1]+s[-1]
def a(n):
 r=''
 for w in n.split():
  if r:r+=' '
  ss=re.split('([AEIOU]+)',w.upper())
  for i,s in enumerate(ss):
   r+=[v(s),s][any(j(t) for t in ss[i+1:])]if j(s)else[s,c(s)][i>0]
 return r
```

Test with:

```
while True:
 print a(raw_input('> '))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you at least golf it down further a little by removing unnecessary spaces and changing `ss` to `S`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 238 bytes

```python
def f(s):
 s=s.upper();k=[s[0]];s=''.join(k+[s[i]for i in range(1,len(s))if s[i]!=s[i-1]])
 for i in range(1,len(s)):k+=[s[i]]*(3-2*(s[i]in'AEIOU'and i!=max(map(s.rfind,'AEIOU'))))
 return''.join(k)
print(' '.join(map(f,input().split())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU67DsIwDNz7FWaKA6XisRVlYGBgYmJCGSI1AdPiRkkqwdeXFCE2bjhbd76T/Svdet6OY2MdOIyyLiCqWA3e24By16pLvKy03kUlRHXvibFdZIm06wMQEEMwfLW4LjvLOS/JwWTPVOblWmtZwL/Tul2oT5ee43a5meO0E4v94Xg6C8MN0Ew9zBMfxmOsgiNuyq8rMwoINg2Bf5/JwgfihAK@yhR0JbEfEsoq@o7yzBhHk5LlRD2D76yJ9g0)

Comment: Can you save bytes by setting `v` to `'AEIOU'`?

Comment: @Zacharý Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't change the bytecount.

Comment: Oh, the spaces around the first `v`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 139 + 1 (-p) = 140 bytes

```perl
$_=uc,s/^([^AEIOU]*)//,$s=$1,s/([^AEIOU])\1*/$1x(($q=length$&)>3?$q:3)/ge,s/.*?\K([AEIOU])\1*/$1x(($q=length$&)>3?$q:3)/e,print"$s$_ "for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rY0WadYP04jOs7R1dM/NFZLU19fR6XYVsUQKAwX1Ywx1NJXMazQ0FAptM1JzUsvyVBR07QztlcptDLW1E9PBSrW07KP8daIJkpDqk5BUWZeiZJKsUq8glJafpGD2///iUCQBATJ//ILSjLz84r/6/qa6hkYGvzXTQQA)

Even handles the "aaaabbbbc" test case in accordance with the example.