# Compare char to other chars in javascript

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

In [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133638/72412), I have this code:

```
s.match(/[AEIOU]/)
```

This seems too verbose to check if a string is one of `A`, `E`, `I`, `O`, or `U`.

I tried:

```
"AEIOU".includes(s)
```

But that's 1 byte longer. Can I do this in a shorter way?

Comment: Before anyone close-votes this, this is a valid tips question.

Comment: I don't think so ...

Comment: `~"AEIOU".indexOf(s)` also works.

Comment: @CloseVoter(s) how is this too broad? It's asking for golfing advice for a specific snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `/[AEIOU]/.test(s)`

<sup>Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 21</sup>

Comment: That's a great way around the character minimum. I almost didn't notice it.

Answer (score 4):

If `s` is a literal and not a variable, you can do the following:

```
/[AEIOU]/.test`A`
"AEIOU".includes`A`
~"AEIOU".indexOf`A`
```

which is shorter than

```
/[AEIOU]/.test("A")
"AEIOU".includes("A")
~"AEIOU".indexOf("A")
```

Comment: Though if it's one of the former the result is deterministic and you can golf it down to one byte 1 and 0

Comment: @Downgoat I was mostly sharing the backticks trick - usually this would be used with `"AEIOU"` is not a constant, so `s.includes<backtick>A<backtick>`

Comment: The backticks trick isn't relevant here...

Answer (score 2):

`` s.match`[AEIOU]` `` goes well.....

Comment: That doesn't work...

Comment: @ASCII-only, it works, just l4m2 had to pay the price of not using code block markup.

Comment: @manatwork ah, I see